# Index of the closed trajectory

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the system

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{dt}=x(1-x-y) \\
\frac{dy}{dt}=y(-1+2x)
\end{cases}
$$

Show that closed orbits are impossible for this system using index theory and properties of the solution curves.

The fixed points of this system are: $(0,0),(1,0),(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}).$ I've drawn a global phase portrait, which clearly shows that there is no closed trajectory. But how do I show that using index theory? Note: Index of curve $$ with respect to vector ﬁeld $(,)$ is $(,,)=$ number of times the vector turns counter-clockwise 
[image]

Comment: can you describe and/or provide a link as to what "index theory" is

Comment: @phdmba7of12, I'm following Strogatz "Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos", and it's chapter 6.8. Here is the link to the book: http://www.hds.bme.hu/~fhegedus/Strogatz%20-%20Nonlinear%20Dynamics%20and%20Chaos.pdf

Comment: the key might be the equation at the top of page 175 $$\phi=\tan^{-1}\frac{\dot{y}}{\dot{x}}$$ take the path integral of $\phi$ around a closed contour and divide by $2\pi$?